# Any way to auto-update cyanogenmod with encryption enabled?

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption

I've been enjoying cyanogenmod a lot, but the auto-updates don't work, since I encrypted the phone.  I'd like to have both, if possible, even if there's a bit of work involved.

Is there any fix / third-party tool that can auto-update an encrypted cyanogenmod installation?

Answer (score 1):

Auto updates are not available yet, but you can update your phone with this recipe:  https://www.bfccomputing.com/updating-cyanogenmod-11-kitkat-milestones-on-encrypted-devices/

Worked smoothly for me between CM 11 versions on a Galaxy Note 2 (t0lte).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set up an additional unencrypted partition, or add an unencrypted sdcard (if your device has a slot - not my Nexus 7) and mount it up and copy over the update file before flashing, it will work.